# UIDatePicker replacement for tvOS?

Tags: tvos

Since UIDatePicker is not available in tvOS, what does one use to ask the user for date/time? Is there a new class that replaces `UIDatePicker`?

Thanks

Comment: I believe there is no current implementation for a UIDatePicker. I was looking for one for my own project and I ended up simulating one with a table view with 3 sections (dd-MM-yyyy). Hope it helps :)

Comment: Open source alternative for tvOS https://github.com/ViacomInc/TVOSPicker

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple does not provide a date picker for tvOS, there is no standard solution.

However, some possible steps would be:

1. Design and implement a UI for manipulating the date components (= year, month, day, hour, minute).
2. Keep track of the currently selected date, e.g. using a stored property. A date label can be updated using property observers (e.g.
   `didSet`).
3. Implement methods for manipulating the selected date - component by component - and connect them to the UI.

Remember that dates and date calculations are complicated(!), so use the provided date concepts and methods - have a look at [Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar) and `DateComponents` in the documentation.

There, you will find useful methods, for example:

- `range(of: Calendar.Component, in: Calendar.Component, for: Date)`
  can be used to find the number of months in a year, days in a month
  (and so on).
- `dateComponents(Set<Calendar.Component>, from: Date)` and `date(from:
  DateComponents)` can be used to convert from dates to date components
  and vice versa.
- Further, `isValidDate(in: Calendar)` can be useful to check that date
  components form a valid date in a certain calendar.

---

Below is a link to the user interface (with `UISegmentedControl`s) that I developed for my app, however, there are other solutions such as the one linked by *ergoon*.

[User interface with segmented controls.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U65DM.jpg)

In my case, the date picker is presented modally after selecting a table view cell in an input form.